# Networkx, tweets from a json file

Tags: python, json, twitter, networkx

I am trying to append tweets from a json file to a Nerworkx graph but I am getting couple of errors. First of all I am getting an erroneous number of nodes (as we can be seen in the last code block). Also this might be related with the first error but I am getting some nodes id's in scientific notation and I am pretty sure that they are just copies of the other nodes. It's important to mention that in this example I am limiting the number of tweets to 100 for computational speed sake.

```
graph = nx.DiGraph()

sadsa = data.copy()
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.f' % x)

sadsa = sadsa[['user','created_at','id','in_reply_to_status_id','text','lang', 'extended_tweet']].head(100)
sadsa.in_reply_to_status_id.fillna(sadsa.id, inplace=True)
sadsa.loc[sadsa['extended_tweet'].isnull(),'extended_tweet'] = sadsa['text']
sadsa.to_json(r'f44.json', orient='records')

import json
dixa = 'f44.json'
with open(dixa) as f: #takes in a jsonl file of tweets as input
    for line in f:
        fixad = json.loads(line)
lista = []
for x in range(0,len(fixad)):
    lista.append(fixad[x])


for x in lista:
    tweet = x
    if 'id' in tweet:
        graph.add_node(tweet['id'],
                        tweet=tweet['extended_tweet'],
                        author=tweet['user']['id'],
                        created_at=tweet['created_at'])
        graph.add_edge(tweet['in_reply_to_status_id'], tweet['id'])

print(nx.info(graph))
```

This is the expected json file

```
'user': {'id': 3321144051,
  'id_str': '3321144051',
  'name': 'Jason Unsworth',
  'screen_name': 'JasonUnsworth2',
  'location': 'United Kingdom and Thailand ',
  'url': 'https://uk.linkedin.com/pub/jason-unsworth/67/51a/3bb',
  'description': 'Founder & CEO of @atmosphereairuk & @atmosphereairth supporting #Brexit by establishing a new premium airline group in 4 different Countries, ����������������',
  'translator_type': 'none',
  'protected': False,
  'verified': False,
  'followers_count': 2898,
  'friends_count': 5000,
  'listed_count': 343,
  'favourites_count': 58774,
  'statuses_count': 76996,
  'created_at': 'Fri Jun 12 16:01:52 +0000 2015',
  'utc_offset': None,
  'time_zone': None,
  'geo_enabled': True,
  'lang': None,
  'contributors_enabled': False,
  'is_translator': False,
  'profile_background_color': 'C0DEED',
  'profile_background_image_url': 'http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
  'profile_background_image_url_https': 'https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
  'profile_background_tile': False,
  'profile_link_color': '1DA1F2',
  'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'C0DEED',
  'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'DDEEF6',
  'profile_text_color': '333333',
  'profile_use_background_image': True,
  'profile_image_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1121042618119364608/JHbFwr3x_normal.jpg',
  'profile_image_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1121042618119364608/JHbFwr3x_normal.jpg',
  'profile_banner_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/3321144051/1551096371',
  'default_profile': True,
  'default_profile_image': False,
  'following': None,
  'follow_request_sent': None,
  'notifications': None},
 'created_at': 'Wed May 22 16:27:30 +0000 2019',
 'id': 1131235144520601603,
 'in_reply_to_status_id': 1.131235145e+18,
 'text': 'RT @AcaaiNews: .@VirginAtlantic ’s Mumbai-Heathrow flight to make available 26 tonnes of #Cargo capacity\n\n#aviation #AvGeek',
 'lang': 'en',
 'extended_tweet': 'RT @AcaaiNews: .@VirginAtlantic ’s Mumbai-Heathrow flight to make available 26 tonnes of #Cargo capacity\n\n#aviation #AvGeek'}
```

This is the nx.info output

```
Name: 
Type: DiGraph
Number of nodes: 189
Number of edges: 100
Average in degree:   0.5291
Average out degree:   0.5291
```